# How to get UILabel Size according to device wise in cellForRowAtIndexPath and UILabel in Custom UITableViewCell, I use Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout

**I use AutoLayout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

I want UILabel Size which in UITableView Cell according.
I made my Custom Cell in iPhone 8 size but in iPhone 5 When I NSLog UILabel size in cellForRowAtIndexPath I get size according to iPhone 8.
I can not get UILabel Size according to iPhone 5.

How can I get Actual size of UILabel According to Device wise for example iPhone5, iPhone6 and so on

Here is my code link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z2bHhKS_s6P6uICqssaW0gNTDGM-p9vL

Comment: what have try to get UILabel size?

Comment: just use NSLog to print size of UILabel

Comment: I mean, Which code you use to print size

Comment: NSLog(@"\n lblPostDesc1 : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.lblPostDesc.frame));

Comment: i also used bounds but not working

Comment: set the numberOfLine of label 0, and set line brake mode wordWrap also in table view --> tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewRowAutomaticDimension and tableView.estimateRowHeight = 150.0, check , tell me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177737/discussion-between-ankur-patel-and-saurabh-jain).

Comment: are you trying to acheive dynamic cell heights based on label text in table view cell?

Comment: No I want UILabel size. My Custom Cell and storyboard design in iPhone 8
and when I run project in iPhone5 I want UILabel size according to iPhone5 wise but I get Size according to iPhone8 wise

Comment: The cell is not sized until it is displayed. If you check the frames in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, you will see the new sizes. The bigger question is: ***why do you want to get the frame sizes?***